# In Probability, what does $\leq_{ST}$ mean? (context in question)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

It is used in the following way, given subsets of the sample space
$$A_1, \cdots, A_n \subset \Omega$$
such that $\mathbb{P}(A_i) \leq \theta$.

Now define i.i.d. Bernoulli r.v.s $B_i \sim Ber(\theta)$, then 
$$(\chi_{A_1} , \cdots, \chi_{A_n}) \leq_{ST} (B_1, \cdots, B_n).$$

What does this $\leq_{ST}$ mean precisely?

Comment: Probably "stochastic domination." I don't remember the definition though.

Comment: It's called stochastic order, just look it up.

Comment: Thank you all .